# How create a single main title to a multiple PieCharts from lessR package?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I was able to create multiple piecharts using the "add" parameter, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283833/placing-two-pie-charts-from-lessr-side-by-side-in-one-figure).

My charts:
[image: My charts]

Now I'm trying to use a single title to these multiple charts. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

My actual code is this:

```
library(lessR)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
PieChart(Classificacao_clinica, hole = 0, values = "%", values_color = "black", values_size = 1.0,
         values_digits = 1, data = df_botropico_2022, fill = c("lightgreen", "orange", "red", "lightgrey"),
         main = "Botrópico", add = PieChart(Classificacao_clinica, 
         hole = 0, values = "%", values_color = "black", values_size = 1.0, values_digits = 1, 
         data = df_crotalico_2022, fill = c("lightgreen", "orange", "red", "lightgrey"), main = "Crotálico",
         add = PieChart(Classificacao_clinica, hole = 0, values = "%", values_color = "black", 
         values_size = 1.0, values_digits = 1, data = df_elapidico_2022, 
         fill = c("lightgreen", "orange", "red", "lightgrey"), main = "Elapídico", 
         add = PieChart(Classificacao_clinica, hole = 0, values = "%", values_color = "black", 
         values_size = 1.0, values_digits = 1, data = df_laquetico_2022, fill = c("lightgreen", "orange", "red", "lightgrey"),
         main = "Laquético"))))
```